# Qt 5.13.2.0 possible malware Variant.Adware.Kazy.795337 in qwebp.dll

Tags: qt, malware

today we received info from one of our customer about this malware detection:

Gen:Variant.Adware.Kazy.795337

It's only inside the qwebp.dll file attached to our project by qtdeploy process.

We're building 32-bit Qt (5.13.2.0) from the source and the same issue is reported on the same DLL no matter where it was built. We're using the latest VS 2019.

- https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/9f09c05803ad4ffcd99454c420a840e17549ee711690fb1f11fd1b59bccc3b23/detection
- https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/80c4c747d781a27c72de71c0900ccc045aefd2b4e4f17c949aaeeb3d0b7973b1/detection

When I scanned the older version (5.13.0.0) everything is ok:

Previous versions seem to be clean:

- https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/b7b7cacaef0e76439ef8c367c401524e93dfa00c9ca67a20290e829fec325a5a/detection

Also, any debug build and 64-bit builds are clean too.

Any idea what can cause this? Can anyone else please try to scan this file?

Thanks

Comment: Note, that only 10 of 69 engines reported this. Maybe false positive?

Comment: Sure, it can be false-positive and probably it is. But it's strange for me why this is happening only in 5.13.2.0 and not 5.13.0.0. Also it's hard to explain to customers that this is false-positive.

Comment: As you mention Web.: I once wrote a helper tool to translate HTML entities into XML entities and vice versa (for my personal purposes). I copied all the HTML entities I could find in an online doc. into a big table of my application (as strings). This application was continuously suspected by Avira for being potential dangerous... :-) (The mere appearance of all these HTML entities inside the binary was probably the suspicious fact.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It is probably nothing, but notify Qt anyway (and check your own systems).

Are you using the prebuilt Qt binaries or are you compiling the sources yourself?
If you are using the official prebuilt binaries, I'd of course expect that the Qt Devteam scans them and verifies that they don't accidently spread malware, but there is always the miniscule chance of something slipping through.
Same goes for the sources - while their review process should be thorough enough to avoid malicious code being slipped in, there is still the outside chance of either a key account being compromised or (even more unlikely) bad code being added slice-by-slice over a longer time period to avoid detection (along the lines of the underhanded C contest). Still, either case seems to be rather unlikely.

**Bottom line:** while this does sound like (and probably is) a *false positive*, you still may want to raise an issue with Qt e.g. on the their [Bugtracking site](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTBUG/issues/QTBUG-80175?filter=allopenissues) or directly with [Qt support](https://login.qt.io/login) (if you have a commercial license) to be sure. Also (if you didn't do that already) verify that the problem is not on your end, e.g. that your computers are clean and that you don't just randomly catch/detect your infection in that file.

**Update:**
A [ticket concerning this issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80189) was opened (I assume by Ludek Vodicka) on Qt bugtracker. Opened on Nov 19th and categorized as P1: Critical, but unfortunately no indication that it is actually being worked on (at least of Dec 18th).

Comment: Thanks for the message. We already scanned all our build machines as same as dev machines. The only reported file is qweb.dll. We're compiling Qt from source and based on our testing this happens only on 5.13.2 release builds when building with the latest VS2019 in 32-bit. We also tried to compare it with precompiled Qt binaries, but they are still compiling with VS2017 where this issue also doesn't occur.

Comment: I already posted that also to the Qt forum but it's a probably good idea to write it also directly to Qt bug tracking system.